# How to do IIS HOSTING WITH ASP.NET CORE 1.0.3 with angular2 application

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.1

I have created an asp.net core 1.0 project with angular  in visual studio 2015 update 3 and  I am new to .net core hosting , the project is running in local machine and when i published the .net core app in iis, I have followed the below steps provided ms documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore1x

Qn: 1
I have installed the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle 2.0 for dotnet 1.0.3 
Windows Server Hosting bundle 2.0  support dotnet core 1.03.

[image]

Version of Dotnet.
In IIS i have change the Application pool to No manage code.

[image]

Asp.net core Folder structure publish
[image]

Note: 
I have Installed .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle.
Configure the IIS and Given the Permission for the Project.
Change the .net framework to .net manage code .
The application ran [image]perfectly in local machine.

Is it possible to host .net core 1.0.3 based angular2 application in iis?

[image]

If anyone can done before?

[image]

Here is the published webconfig file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Angular2Seed.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 32c02de9-da04-4bb4-b20b-93df756b9828-->
```

Comment: `ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` means that you can't use that port.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks man i have corrected and updated my question still not working , i will provide the repository which i have published ,if you could help, please help

Comment: Can you please share web.config from publish location in question?

Comment: @sanket i have provided webconfig file and the published file here https://github.com/MohamedSahir/Angular2IISPUBLISSH